# How can i disable opatch job?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, patching

I have a docker 12.2 oracle db for localhoat dev. I don't care if it's patched regularly. I'm seeing constant errors In qopatch queries. I think its triggered by some batch job at startup and maybe at regular intervals. I looked at the dump but can't make much of it. There is some table that has a preprocessor pointing at a .bat file (why .bat when the os is linux?) that is failing. I read some post to delete and recreate the table. I'm no dba. I can do without the patching. It's in a sandbox and no real data so idc about security as much and don't plan to patch until my org updates to latest version. At that point I'll reimage the local database anyway. Not in front of my computer but can post more details later if needed. Thanks!

Edit:
here is what I am seeing in the logs. No idea what these errors are or what other details I should post.

ORCLPDB1(3):Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.

See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.

2021-10-19T00:09:14.233124+00:00

Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orclcdb/ORCLCDB/trace/ORCLCDB_j001_6161.trc (incident=15049) (PDBNAME=ORCLPDB1):

KUP-00600: internal error, arguments [kudmpgnc:badbl] [0] [] [] []

ORCLPDB1(3):Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.

See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.

Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orclcdb/ORCLCDB/trace/ORCLCDB_j001_6161.trc (incident=15050) (PDBNAME=ORCLPDB1):

KUP-00600: internal error, arguments [kudmpgnc:badbl] [0] [] [] []

ORCLPDB1(3):Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.

See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.

ORCLPDB1(3):TABLE SYS.WRI$_OPTSTAT_HISTHEAD_HISTORY: ADDED INTERVAL PARTITION SYS_P248 (44487) VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2021-10-20 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))

ORCLPDB1(3):TABLE SYS.WRI$_OPTSTAT_HISTGRM_HISTORY: ADDED INTERVAL PARTITION SYS_P251 (44487) VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2021-10-20 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))

2021-10-19T00:09:16.098169+00:00

Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orclcdb/ORCLCDB/trace/ORCLCDB_j001_6161.trc (incident=15051) (PDBNAME=ORCLPDB1):

KUP-00600: internal error, arguments [kudmpgnc:badbl] [0] [] [] []

ORCLPDB1(3):Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.

See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.

2021-10-19T00:09:19.830473+00:00

TABLE SYS.WRI$_OPTSTAT_HISTHEAD_HISTORY: ADDED INTERVAL PARTITION SYS_P347 (44487) VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2021-10-20 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))

TABLE SYS.WRI$_OPTSTAT_HISTGRM_HISTORY: ADDED INTERVAL PARTITION SYS_P350 (44487) VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE(' 2021-10-20 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))

2021-10-19T00:19:13.566580+00:00

Resize operation completed for file# 3, old size 839680K, new size 849920K

2021-10-19T00:19:16.977835+00:00

Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orclcdb/ORCLCDB/trace/ORCLCDB_j000_6425.trc (incident=15089) (PDBNAME=ORCLPDB1):

KUP-00600: internal error, arguments [kudmpgnc:badbl] [0] [] [] []

ORCLPDB1(3):Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.

See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.

Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orclcdb/ORCLCDB/trace/ORCLCDB_j000_6425.trc (incident=15090) (PDBNAME=ORCLPDB1):

KUP-00600: internal error, arguments [kudmpgnc:badbl] [0] [] [] []

ORCLPDB1(3):Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.

See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.

2021-10-19T00:19:18.750419+00:00

Errors in file /u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orclcdb/ORCLCDB/trace/ORCLCDB_j000_6425.trc (incident=15091) (PDBNAME=ORCLPDB1):

KUP-00600: internal error, arguments [kudmpgnc:badbl] [0] [] [] []

ORCLPDB1(3):Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.

See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.

Comment: more details needed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this and I have not seen any more of these errors in the mean time:

```
exec dbms_scheduler.disable('LOAD_OPATCH_INVENTORY');
```

Still too early to tell but that seems to be the culprit.